# Append a series of values to a dataframe as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append

I have a loop that selects a particular column from a pivot table and stores it as a series.

'ar' is a pandas dataframe that contains numerous columns. One of the columns is 'year of application', which is used below:

```
for i, row in ar.iterrows():
    GC_t1 = audit_pivot['GC', (row['year_of_application']-1)] # GS for t-1
    GC_t2 = audit_pivot['GC', (row['year_of_application']-2)] # GS for t-2
```

I want to append each of these series as a new column until the end of the loop (so that each iteration of GC_t1 and GC_t2 are new columns). How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses. In particular you should post `ar` (or a sample of it) and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by `append each of these series as a new column`, but I you could do something like this:

```
gc_t1_dfs = []
gc_t1_dfs = []
for i, row in ar.iterrows():
    gc_t1_dfs.append(pd.Series(audit_pivot['GC', (row['year_of_application']-1)]).to_frame())
    gc_t2_dfs.append(pd.Series(audit_pivot['GC', (row['year_of_application']-2)]).to_frame())

GC_t1_df = pd.concat(gc_t1_dfs)
GC_t2_df = pd.concat(gc_t2_dfs)
```

It's unclear what `ar` and `audit_pivot` look like, but I wouldn't recommend iterating through `ar` because it can be really inefficient. Instead, try something along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
gc_t1_vals = np.ravel(audit_pivot['GC'][(ar['year_of_application']-1).tolist()].values)
gc_t2_vals = np.ravel(audit_pivot['GC'][(ar['year_of_application']-2).tolist()].values)

gc_t_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(gc_t1_vals, gc_t2_vals), columns=["GC T1", "GC T2"])
```

It all depends on what `ar` and `audit_pivot` look like.